# jFormDesigner design it won't display?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jform-designer

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;

/**
 * @author Ene Ion
 */
public class launcher extends JFrame {

        public launcher() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Ene Ion
        mbmlauncherfata = new JFrame();
        textField1 = new JTextField();
        checkBox1 = new JCheckBox();
        label1 = new JLabel();
        comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        label2 = new JLabel();
        comboBox2 = new JComboBox();
        button1 = new JButton();
        button2 = new JButton();
        button3 = new JButton();
        progressBar1 = new JProgressBar();
        label3 = new JLabel();
        label4 = new JLabel();
        button4 = new JButton();
        button5 = new JButton();
        label5 = new JLabel();
        button6 = new JButton();

        //======== mbmlauncherfata ========
        {
            mbmlauncherfata.setTitle("MBMLauncher");
            mbmlauncherfata.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("E:\\Chituri\\MBMLauncherJava\\src\\resursele\\icon_4_64x64x32.png").getImage());
            mbmlauncherfata.setResizable(false);
            Container mbmlauncherfataContentPane = mbmlauncherfata.getContentPane();

            //---- textField1 ----
            textField1.setText("Username");
            textField1.setForeground(new Color(153, 0, 0));

            //---- checkBox1 ----
            checkBox1.setText("Remember Me");

            //---- label1 ----
            label1.setText("RAM Allocated");

            //---- comboBox1 ----
            comboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
                "256M",
                "512M",
                "1024M",
                "2G",
                "3G",
                "4G"
            }));

            //---- label2 ----
            label2.setText("to");

            //---- comboBox2 ----
            comboBox2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {
                "512M",
                "1024M",
                "2G",
                "3G",
                "4G",
                "5G",
                "6G"
            }));

            //---- button1 ----
            button1.setText("Play");
            button1.setFont(new Font("Snap ITC", Font.BOLD, 36));
            button1.setForeground(new Color(255, 102, 0));

            //---- button2 ----
            button2.setText("Update Game");

            //---- button3 ----
            button3.setText("Update Launcher");

            //---- label3 ----
            label3.setText("Download status:");

            //---- label4 ----
            label4.setText("Nothing in download");

            //---- button4 ----
            button4.setText("Texture Packs");

            //---- button5 ----
            button5.setText(".game");

            //---- label5 ----
            label5.setText("Drag and drop your texture\npack in the box *.zip files");
            label5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("E:\\Chituri\\MBMLauncherJava\\src\\resursele\\dasdasdasd.png"));

            //---- button6 ----
            button6.setText("Made By Malasuerte94");

            GroupLayout mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout = new GroupLayout(mbmlauncherfataContentPane);
            mbmlauncherfataContentPane.setLayout(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout);
            mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addComponent(progressBar1, GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(button1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(button2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(button3, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 140, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(button4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 130, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(button5, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(textField1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(checkBox1))
                            .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(label1)
                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(comboBox1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(label2)
                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(comboBox2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(label3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 96, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(label4))
                            .addComponent(label5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 270, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(button6, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addContainerGap())
            );
            mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(checkBox1)
                            .addComponent(textField1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(label2)
                            .addComponent(comboBox2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(label1)
                            .addComponent(comboBox1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(button1)
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(button2)
                            .addComponent(button3))
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(progressBar1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 18, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(label4)
                            .addComponent(label3))
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(mbmlauncherfataContentPaneLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(button4)
                            .addComponent(button5))
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(label5)
                        .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(button6, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(10, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            mbmlauncherfata.setSize(305, 395);
            mbmlauncherfata.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Ene Ion
    private JFrame mbmlauncherfata;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JCheckBox checkBox1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JComboBox comboBox1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JComboBox comboBox2;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JProgressBar progressBar1;
    private JLabel label3;
    private JLabel label4;
    private JButton button4;
    private JButton button5;
    private JLabel label5;
    private JButton button6;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                launcher GUI = new launcher();
                GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                GUI.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Result is a empty java box..
[picture](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/4373/wtfjp.jpg)
I try to fix this problem but i am beginer in java scripting, where is the problem and how i can fix it ?
Tanks for helping, and recomand me please some good plugins for Eclipse.

Comment: I recommend you put the form designer to the side and learn to code Swing first by hand. The Swing tutorials will help you in this. Then later when you understand Swing, sure, go ahead and use a form designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually happens when the frame is not packed.

Try this:

```
launcher GUI = new launcher();
GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
GUI.pack(); // <=========== PACK 
GUI.setVisible(true);
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) is a nice tutorial that will get you started with Java frames.

Comment: same.. i make the change but keep empty

Comment: Are you sure you did not change the auto generated code? Try to set the form's preferred size to something sensible